# How to get Exact Matching List object based on list of Int?

Tags: c#, .net, list, object

I want to Exact Matching List of object based on list of int 
I have two list, first
`List<int> list1 = new List<int>(){5,6};`-- assume these are university Ids
second I have list of objects like 
`List<UniversityGroup> list2 = new List<UniversityGroup>();`
`new UniversityGroup ({UniversityGroupId = 1 ,UniversityId = 5 });`objects matched o/p should'1'
`new UniversityGroup ({UniversityGroupId = 1 ,UniversityId = 6 });`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
`new UniversityGroup ({UniversityGroupId = 2 ,UniversityId = 5 });`--ignored as it contains just '5'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
`new UniversityGroup ({UniversityGroupId = 3 ,UniversityId = 2 });`--ignored elements are not matching
`new UniversityGroup ({UniversityGroupId = 3 ,UniversityId = 3 });`

And wanted output as **universityGroupId** Where ids from list1 will match with **UniversityId from list2** ,
Expected Output`:=>`
 `[1]` or 
`new UniversityGroup ({UniversityGroupId = 1 ,UniversityId = 5 });`
`new UniversityGroup ({UniversityGroupId = 1 ,UniversityId = 6 });`

I have tried using `foreach` but ,I dont think its an optimized solution, so looking for shorthand or optimized linq query .

Comment: *I have tried using foreach but ,I dont think its an optimized solution, so looking for ... linq query* - what do you think LINQ uses internally? :)

Comment: linq internally uses foreach i know, but i had written un-optimized code using some couple of foreach loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I get your problem statement right, you might be able to leverage of [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8) in your query:

```cs
    var list1 = new List<int> { 5, 6 };
    var list2 = new List<UniversityGroup> {
        new UniversityGroup{ UniversityGroupId = 1 ,UniversityId = 6 },
        new UniversityGroup{ UniversityGroupId = 1, UniversityId = 5 },
        new UniversityGroup{ UniversityGroupId = 2, UniversityId = 5 },
        new UniversityGroup{ UniversityGroupId = 3, UniversityId = 2 },
        new UniversityGroup{ UniversityGroupId = 3, UniversityId = 3 }
    };
    list1.Sort(); // depending on your input data you might want to apply some ordering so you could match sequences 6,5 to 5,6
    var result = list2.GroupBy(g => g.UniversityGroupId)
                    .Where(g => g.Select(i => i.UniversityId)
                                .OrderBy(x => x) // this might be optional if you can guarantee source sequence order
                                .SequenceEqual(list1)) // here's the thing
                    //.Select(g => g.Key) // if you want just UniversityGroupId
                 ;
```

It is however hard to say whether this query is going to be any better than your couple of *foreach* loops without seing those.

Comment: Could you not just ask if the group collection contains All the list1?