# While querying IQueryable with linq subquery it fail

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, in-subquery

I just want use an `IQueryable` fetched from EF Core to filter customers against a filter, in this case the filter is another list of customers.

After hours of search I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2381086) and it looks works ok, then I tried do this:

```
List<Customer> filteredCustomers = iqueryable.Join(customersListAsFilter.Select(F => F.Id), F => F.Id, Id => Id, (T, S) => T).ToList<Customer>();
```

and got this cryptic error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Join(
> outer: __p_0,
> inner: F => F.Id,
> outerKeySelector: Id => Id,
> innerKeySelector: (T, S) => T)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression query)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at MyProjectDir.shared.MyDbClass.Read(List`1 customers) in C:\MyProjectDir\shared\MyDbClass.cs:line 35
> at MyProjectDir.shared.MyDbClass.Read(Customer customer) in C:\MyProjectDir\shared\MyDbClass.cs:line 42
> at WTAPP.Controllers.CustomerController.Get(Int32 Id) in C:\MyProjectDir\MyWebProj\CustomerController.cs:line 37
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()

Another alternative I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60125965) and I tried this:

```
var result = q.GroupBy(target => target.Id)
              .Where(target => target.Select(T => T.Id)
              .OrderBy(Id => Id)
              .SequenceEqual(customersListAsFilter));
```

But in this case, I get this error:

> Error CS1929
> 'IOrderedEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'SequenceEqual' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.SequenceEqual(ParallelQuery, IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery'

Comment: I don't get why you have a list of Customers and then you query the db to give you all the Customers you already have. What do you need the DB to supply that you don't already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `iqueryable` variable is an `IQueryable<Customer>`, and you are trying to get a subset of customers based on what you have in `customersListAsFilter`, you can do the following:

```
List<int> customersToGet = customersListAsFilter.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
List<Customer> filteredCustomers = iqueryable.Where(x => customersToGet.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

The generated query will be something like:

```
select * -- (column names)
from Customers
where Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6) -- the IDs from customersToGet
```